# Way of deploying geoserver on tomcat8?

Tags: geoserver, deployment

**objective :**

Save time in setting geoserver configuration specially in case like updating configuration from development environment to production **or** quickly create a copy for experimentation

**What i know :**

I can deploy geoserver by copying the war file in the tomcat webapps folder then tomcat automatically creates geoserver folder

**What i want to know :**

what if i copied the geoserver folder from say tomcat on server 1 to tomcat on server 2 . 
Will it work ?
Any precautions ?

**Note :** I am for now NOT setting geoserver data dir in path

Comment: It should work I think, at least when the java and tomcat version are the same. But I did not try, so not posting an answer. Why not just try it? You might need to set the context manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might work or it might fail horribly, rather depends on what operating system, what layers you have deployed, plugins etc.

It would be **much safer** to use a data directory outside of tomcat and copy that over to the new machine and allow tomcat to deploy the war file pointing to that directory.